# SMTP Error with PHPMailer and Gmail: Network Unreachable

Tags: php, smtp, phpmailer

I'm sorry that this has been asked before, but I can't get my contact form php to work.

This is my code:

```
<?php
  use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
  use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

  require 'PHPMailer-master/src/Exception.php';
  require 'PHPMailer-master/src/PHPMailer.php';
  require 'PHPMailer-master/src/SMTP.php';
    
  if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  $mail = new PHPMailer(true);
  $mail->isSMTP();
  $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
  $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
  $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
  $mail->Port = 465;
  $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
  $mail->SMTPOptions = array(
    'ssl' => array(
        'verify_peer' => false,
        'verify_peer_name' => false,
        'allow_self_signed' => true
    )
);
  $mail->isHTML(true);    
  $mail->Username = '****@gmail.com';
  $mail->Password = '****';
  
  $mail->setFrom('*****@gmail.com', 'Mailer');
  $mail->addAddress('*****@yahoo.com');
  $mail->addReplyTo($_POST['email'], $_POST['name']);
  $mail->Subject = 'Test';
  $mail->Body = $_POST['message'];
  $mail->send();

  }


  

?>
```

When I submit my contact form, I get this message:

2021-05-12 04:03:20 SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Network is unreachable (101)
SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting

What do I do to get it to send?

Comment: Port 465 might be unusually (usually they block port 25) blocked by your isp

Comment: Follow that troubleshooting link. It has extensive discussion of this exact problem and how to diagnose it. It is most likely that your hosting provider is blocking outbound SMTP.